# How to apply typecast for two type declarations in typescript? The property toFixed does not exist for the type "string|number"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to access a variable declared as type

```
value: (string|number)
```

in a typescript file in my javascript function that is nested in a Highcharts block.
In my function I need it as number.I always get an error message in my VSC: "The property toFixed does not exist for the type "string|number". How can I make clear at this point that only the type number should be applied here?

```
      formatter: function hasDecimals() {
        if (Number.isInteger(this.value)) {
          return `${this.value} %`;
        }
        return `${this.value.toFixed(2)} %`;
      },
```

I have tried:

````
return `${this.value.toFixed(2) as number} %`; ```

and 

```return `${<number>(this.value.toFixed(2))}
````

and

```
return `${Number(this.value.toFixed(2))}
```

Have expected that the type number will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

"Asserting" isn't really safe here - what's safer would be a runtime check that TypeScript can pick up and use as a way to narrow the type:

```
      formatter: function hasDecimals() {
        const value = this.value;
        if (typeof value !== "number") throw new Error("not a number");
        if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
          return `${value} %`;
        }
        return `${value.toFixed(2)} %`;
      },
```